# JHipster Cloudfoundary throwing "Error uploading application" error

Tags: cloud-foundry, jhipster

I am attempting to push my Jhipster app to cloud foundry using jhipster cloudfoundary command. Right at the end of the process it is throwing an error

```
Error uploading application.
GetFileAttributesEx C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006\target\*.war: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Google is suggesting things like GetFileAttributesEx doesnt like special characters. I cant think what I could be doing to cause a file name syntax error. I tried deleting the target*.war files and re-compiling but no help. I am on Windows 8.1 64, with all updates applied.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006>yo jhipster:cloudfoundry
CloudFoundry configuration is starting
? Name to deploy as: modeldr006
? Which profile would you like to use? dev
? What is the name of your database service? cleardb
? What is the name of your database plan? spark

Creating Cloud Foundry deployment files
identical deploy\cloudfoundry\manifest.yml

Checking for an existing Cloud Foundry hosting environment...

Creating your Cloud Foundry hosting environment, this may take a couple minutes...
Creating the database
Creating service modeldr006 in org ModelDrivers / space development as greg.soulsby@ibpartners.co.uk...

OK


Building the application with the development profile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...


[WARNING]

[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for us.modeldrivers.us:modeldr006:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line
318, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]

[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]

[INFO]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building modeldr006 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-versions) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

[INFO] Copying 9 resources

[INFO] Copying 22 resources


[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!

[INFO] Compiling 115 source files to C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006\target\classes

[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.


[INFO] Copying 2 resources


[INFO]

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO] Tests are skipped.

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO] Packaging webapp

[INFO] Assembling webapp [modeldr006] in [C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006\target\modeldr006-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

[INFO] Processing war project

[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006\src\main\webapp]

[INFO] Webapp assembled in [8576 msecs]

[INFO] Building war: C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006\target\modeldr006-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ modeldr006 ---

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 30.544 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-26T18:16:04+00:00

[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/391M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


Pushing the application to Cloud Foundry
Using manifest file ./deploy/cloudfoundry/manifest.yml


Creating app modeldr006 in org ModelDrivers / space development as greg.soulsby@ibpartners.co.uk...

OK


Using route modeldr006.cfapps.io
Binding modeldr006.cfapps.io to modeldr006...

OK

Uploading modeldr006...

FAILED
Error uploading application.
GetFileAttributesEx C:\IBP\03_Product\modelDR\03_Product\01_Jhipster\modeldr006\target\*.war: The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

× { [Error: Command failed: ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

Comment: it looks to me like the line that is failing is cf push -f ./deploy/cloudfoundry/manifest.yml -p target/*.war. If I replace the * with the app name when running from the command line it works. I am thinking there is a problem with * for the js exec command under windows.

Comment: I don't see why * would be a problem, but as I don't have Windows I can't test it. Anyway: I'm just using * because I don't know the final name of your WAR file, and maybe you changed something in the build process and have more than one WAR -> I've seen this once, and of course it makes the command fail. Can you check if you have more than one ".war" file?

Comment: There is modeldr006-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war and modeldr006-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original, so no dups

Comment: Test on Windows 7 SP1: replace * by war name helps. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I get the same error when my WAR has not built successfully in the target directory, but it doesn't sound like that is the problem for you.

Comment: And even when the WAS is created. It appears that the "cf push" -p argument wants: "Path to app directory or to a zip file of the contents of the app directory" so it's enough to say:
`cf push -f ./deploy/cloudfoundry/manifest.yml -p target`